# Updating an Image in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, pycharm, mouseevent

My first time here so please bare with me.

I'm trying to create a python script using opencv to open an image and then place a dot in the image where a RMB click is. This disappears and another is added if a new position is selected. This continues until a correct position is clicked and then recorded by either MMB or RMB click (although I can't get the RMB click to work in pycharm with `event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN`: it just brings up the options box).

```
import cv2
import numpy

points = []  # need to initialise the list so you can append

def getpoints(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img1, (x,y), 4, (255,255,255), -1)  # the image is stored as img
        cv2.imshow('image', img1)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.imshow('image', img)
        img1 == img

    #elif event == cv2.EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN:
        #points.append([x, y])
        #print(points)

print ("openCV version= " + cv2. __version__)
```

Comment: please ask a question too. [tour], [ask]. opencv is not for making guis. it's good enough for some quick simple gui interactions. in general, you should use a proper gui toolkit. no gui toolkit will get mouse click events from windows that it doesn't own. when you click around in pycharm, those windows belong to pycharm, not to your python script.